# How to calculate anomalies of Geopotential Height in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, mean, reshape

I am interested in calculating GPH anomalies in Matlab. I have a 3D matrix of lat, lon, and time. Where time is a daily GPH value for 32 years (1979-2010). The matrix is 95x38x11689. How do I compute a daily average across all years for each day of data, when the matrix is 3D?

I am ultimately trying to compute the GPH anomaly from the difference of the daily value and the climatological mean of that given day.

In other words, how do I compute the average of Jan. 1st dates for all years to compute the climatological mean of all Jan. 1st's from 1979-2010? And so forth for each day after. The data also includes leap years. How do I handle that?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The 3rd dimension is the GPH data NOT time. It's just the data for every day time step from 1979 to 2011.

Comment: Can I clarify: for your matrix of dimensions (95x38x11689), what values are depicted by the first 2 dimensions 95x38 for each day? If it's latitude/longitude, why are there more values for one than the other? Or is it  3610 GPH values recorded per day?

Comment: @LouisLeung It's because I am plotting over Greenland, and it's more latitudinally-distributed than longitudinally-distributed.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. Looks like you got the help you need so all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
%Using your dimensions make up some fake data
GPH = rand(95,38,11689)
%Get an index into the 3rd dimension for your desired dates
dateIdx = datenum(1979:2010,1,1)-datenum(1979,1,1) + 1;
%Take the mean along the 3rd dimensions
mean_of_all_Jan_1 = mean(GPH(:,:,dateIdx ),3);
```

An example of getting another arbitrary date say every March 15th.  Note that I only changed the first call to `datenum` and not the second.

```
dateIdx = datenum(1979:2010,3,15)-datenum(1979,1,1) + 1;
mean_of_all_March_15 = mean(GPH(:,:,dateIdx ),3);
```

I am assuming that along the 3rd dimension index 1 is Jan 1 1979 & progresses at 1 index per day.

**EDIT to get every day**
This will return a `dailyMeanGPH` that is `95x38x366`.  Such that dailyMeanGPH(:,:,1) is the mean for every Jan 1st, dailyMeanGPH(:,:,2) = Jan 2nd ...
Note that for Feb 29th there will be less days averaged since it will occur 1/4th as often.

Alternative you if comment/uncomment the lines noted in the code below your output can be returned in a cell array.  That way if you wanted Jan 1 mean you would do  `dailyMeanGPH{1,1}` then Jan 2nd  `dailyMeanGPH{1,2}` etc.  Where the index into the cell is `{month,day}` of interest.

```
function dailyMeanGPH = getDailyMeanGPH(GPH)

daysInMonth = [31 29 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31]; %inlcude 29 for Feb
dailyMeanGPH = zeros(size(GPH,1),size(GPH,2),sum(daysInMonth)); %COMMENT OUT IF YOU WNAT OUTPUT IN CELL
% dailyMeanGPH = cell(12,31); %UNCOMMENT IF YOU WANT OUTPUT IN CELL

k = 1;
for m = 1:12
    for d = 1:daysInMonth(m)
        %Get an index into the 3rd dimension for your desired dates
        dateIdx = datenum(1979:2010,m,d)-datenum(1979,1,1) + 1;        
        if m==2 && d ==29 %Purge Feb 29 from non-leap years.
            checkIdx =  datenum(1979:2010,3,1)-datenum(1979,1,1) + 1;
            dateIdx = setdiff(dateIdx,checkIdx);
        end        
         %Take the mean along the 3rd dimensions.
         dailyMeanGPH(:,:,k) = mean(GPH(:,:,dateIdx ),3);%COMMENT OUT IF YOU WNAT OUTPUT IN CELL
         k = k+1;
%          dailyMeanGPH{m,d} = mean(GPH(:,:,dateIdx ),3);%UNCOMMENT IF YOU WANT OUTPUT IN CELL     
    end
end
```

Comment: I mixed up the 3rd dimension. The 3rd dimension is the GPH data NOT time. It's just the data for everyday time step from 1979 to 2011. So instead it would need to sort by, for instance, Jan. 1st indices = 1, 365, 730, etc.

Comment: That is what `dateIdx` is.  if you do that calc you get `dateIdx = 1,366,732 ...`  Using `datenum` will account for the leap years.  Then this part `GPH(:,:,dateIdx )` will get the GPH data for all of those dates (meaning every Jan 1st).

Comment: Ok, I am testing it now. So, how do I loop through that for everyday of the year in a similar fashion?

Comment: See my edit for a function that will loop through each day and return the mean GPH data in either a `95x68x366` or a cell array indexed my month/day.